# Detect if a subnet is enclosed in another

Tags: bash, awk

I have some Bash code to detect if a subnet is fully inside a second subnet. I have achieved this by calling a Python command [`ipconflict`](https://github.com/fgiuba/ipconflict):

```sh
small_net=10.0.0.0/16
big_net=10.0.0.0/24

ipconflict  '0.0.0.0/0' "$small_net" -p 2> /dev/null | \
  sed -n '2,$p' > against_z
ipconflict "$big_net"   "$small_net" -p 2> /dev/null | \
  sed -n '2,$p' > against_p

if ! cmp -s against_z against_p ; then
  echo "$small_net not inside $big_net"
fi
```

The logic here is:

- Compare the small network to 0.0.0.0/0 which yields every IP in the small network.
- Compare the small network to big network which should also yield every IP in the small network.

If the two sets of generated IPs are not identical, then small network is not fully enclosed in the big network.

I can see many problems with this but the main problem is it is too slow, due to the Python tool being slow, and what I can't find is an easier, better, faster way to do this in Bash (or AWK).

(I am more than happy to use external tools but pure Bash or AWK could be even better.)

What is an efficient way to test in Bash (or AWK) that a smaller subnet is fully enclosed in a larger one?

Comment: There isn't an efficient way; `bash` isn't designed for the amount of math required. `ipconflict` can be imported as a module, so you can write your entire script in Python instead. Also, Python is unlikely to be your bottleneck here; you are starting two instance of `sed` to filter the output, the starting `cmp` to compare the results.

Comment: @chepner Thanks removing the seds improves performance a bit but the Python tool is still a bottleneck. The requirement is for this to be in Bash. I thought there might be some tool like ipcalc or something written in C at least I could call. So far no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Likely not efficient, but in plain bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

netenclose () {
    local o1 o2 o3 o4 p1 p2 p3 p4 m1 m2 ip1 ip2 min
    IFS=./ read o1 o2 o3 o4 m1 <<< "$1"
    IFS=./ read p1 p2 p3 p4 m2 <<< "$2"

    ((min = m1 > m2 ? m2 : m1))
    ip1=$(((o1 << 24) + (o2 << 16) + (o3 << 8) + o4))
    ip2=$(((p1 << 24) + (p2 << 16) + (p3 << 8) + p4))

    if (( (ip1 >> (32 - min)) == (ip2 >> (32 - min)) )); then
        if ((m1 > m2)); then
            echo "$1 inside $2"
        else
            echo "$2 inside $1"
        fi
    else
        echo "Not inside"
    fi
}

# Inside
netenclose 10.0.0.0/16 10.0.0.0/24
netenclose 10.0.0.0/24 10.0.0.0/16
# Not inside
netenclose 10.0.0.0/8 192.168.0.0/16
```

Note: Error checking and input validation omitted for brevity.

Comment: Is this algorithm documented somewhere?

Comment: @AlexHarvey I don't know if it is documented somewhere but the algorithm is straightforward from the definition of CIDR.

Comment: @AlexHarvey I've just noticed that there was a typo in the code. Corrected it now.

Comment: @AlexHarvey Please use this current corrected version. I've mixed up `m1` and `m2` while computing the `min` in the previous version.